# iOS7 remoteControlReceivedWithEvent never being called

Tags: iphone, event-handling, ios7, remote-control

I'm building a testing app to see if I can get my app to work with remote control.

I followed the apple documentation for remote control event handling shown at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7-SW3

Right now I have a dummy app that has nothing but the function calls/implementations shown in that article.

I've put some print statements, and found out that

remoteControlReceivedWithEvent is never being called.

I've done some research, and I'm sure I didn't forget to implement

```
canBecomeFirstResponder
```

I even put a print statement in it.

When I press the play button on my apple earpod, it just plays a music from the music app and does nothing else.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

I'm using the latest version of iOS7

=============== Edit 1 ====================

I tested motion and touch event and they seem to be working fine.

It's just the remote controller.

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006282/remotecontrolreceivedwithevent-called-on-ios-7-0-device-but-not-ios-8-0