# remoteControlReceivedWithEvent called on iOS 7.0 device but not iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, ios8, avplayer, ios8.1

I have an application that plays audio in the background. I am trying to fix a bug where the audio controls (play/pause), on the home screen (etc.), DO NOT work on iOS 8.0+ but work FINE on iOS 7.0. I have been digging through trying to figure out what the issue is and have been coming up empty.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have in place.

In the Project Settings:
I have ensured that `UIBackgroundModes` is set to `audio`.

In the AppDelegate.h:
I have a member for the `AVAudioSession* session;` as well as the `AVPlayer *audioPlayer;`

In the AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

self.session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError* error = NULL;
[self.session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
[self.session setActive:YES error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

In the AudioPlayerViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

//Get the Audio
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.audioUrl];
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

//Setup the player
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
appDelegate.audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];

//Setup the "Now Playing"
NSMutableDictionary *mediaInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[mediaInfo setObject:self.title forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
[mediaInfo setObject:self.artist forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
[mediaInfo setObject:self.album forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
[mediaInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:duration ] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:mediaInfo];
```

}

```
// Process remote control events
- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

NSLog(@"AudioPlayerViewController ... remoteControlReceivedWithEvent top ....subtype: %d", event.subtype);

if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

    switch (event.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            [self togglePlayPause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            [self doPause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
            [self doPause];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            [self doPlay];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
            [self nextOrPrevTrack];
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
            [self nextOrPrevTrack];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

}

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self resignFirstResponder];
```

}

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue I was having.  Ultimately it seemed that the events from the Remote Control on the home screen were never making it into my app and down to my view controllers.  I ended up subclassing the `UIWindow` so that I could see what events were making their way through the chain.  As `UIWindow` is a `UIResponder` I also added the `- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to the subclass.  Then in the makeKeyAndVisible I added the:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

I started up the debugger and the `-(void)makeKeyAndVisible` was never called!  I then searched my app delegate for the `window` member variable and the `[window makeKeyAndVisible];` line was nowhere to be found! I added it back in (as it should have been there) and presto events are routing to the correct locations like magic.  Why this was working on some versions of iOS and not others and without any other noticeable issues is beyond me.

Hope this helps someone out in the future.

Comment: can you post some relevant code on how you made it work? Like how and where you did the subclassing of the `UIWindow`?

Comment: The problem was the missing [window makeKeyAndVisible] call.  Not anything to do with the subclassing the UIWindow class.

Answer (score 4):

In your ViewController add

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
}

override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent) {
        // your stuff
    }
```

In AppDelegate add

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

var error: NSError?
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &error)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: &error)
}
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
self.becomeFirstResponder()

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch {
    print("hmmm...")
}
```

Comment: What happens when you have multiple ViewControllers of which one is they Player and you switch to another ViewController.  How do you continue to handle the remotes in the PlayerController that is now "destroyed" ?

Comment: Good point: I think than you should handle such behaviour in your AppDelegate or in a Singleton Object

Comment: That is the correct answer.  added logic  AppDelegate to call the methods in the view controller since the players are static.